# Smooth curves with variable width

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [‘Poster’ fountain pen nib style text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16899/poster-fountain-pen-nib-style-text)

Does exist any TikZ library with the help of which it is possible to draw smooth curved lines with variable width? I mean to set just one path, something like calligraphy letters.

Comment: Would the approach in the answer I linked to help you?

Comment: There's also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14283/86

Comment: I had on my mind different [type of lines](http://images.clipartof.com/small/1053212-Royalty-Free-Vector-Clip-Art-Illustration-Of-A-Digital-Collage-Of-Black-And-White-Ornate-Calligraphic-Design-Elements-1.jpg) Longer paths, where the thickness can be adujsted for different segments.