# How to make a "krul" (unofficial Dutch symbol for OK)

Tags: symbols

Time and again I have been wanting to use a *krul/krulletje* in my documents. For instance in proofs consisting of multiple parts, as an alternative `\qedsymbol`, etc. But never could I find one.

How can I get it?

**EDIT**: 
N.B. The krul can come in different forms. Compare for instance the tails of
[image: krul 1] and [image: krul 2].

I personally consider the first one sloppy and the second one desireable. But this is of course a very unofficial and hanwaving definition of what the krul should actually look like. I bet there will also be people who prefer the first type.

A short example of the krul in use can be seen [here](https://youtu.be/3f6ESRnFTdw?t=17s).

Comment: If anyone knows a different/better way to draw a krul than in my own answer, please don't hesitate to post it as an answer.

Comment: Interesting. This  posting suggests that it doesn't really exist in Unicode and supports in fonts is lacking generally not just in tex  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58320/what-is-the-name-or-unicode-for-this-symbol-similar-to-%E2%82%B0-dutch-called-krul

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Which is a shame, because it's a really common symbol in The Netherlands.

Comment: you could ask the UTC to add it.... http://www.unicode.org/pending/proposals.html

Comment: Common in handwriting, or do you mean you can do this in Word etc ? (and if so what does it do)

Comment: In handwriting, yes. There does not seem to be any standard way to get this symbol.

Comment: in that case getting it into Unicode could be tricky (references to existing published use being the main thing they look for) (even if you have to go back to pre-digital typeset documents to find a book using it)

Comment: I can't think of any books right now, but there are probaly some Dutch schoolbooks where the wrong use of something and the correct use of something are compared. The wrong example would then be marked by a (red) cross and the right one by a (green) krul. An example of this use can be seen [here](https://youtu.be/3f6ESRnFTdw?t=17s). Should there not be any books containing the symbol, I'm willing to bet that any random exercise book, found at a random Dutch elementary school, will contain krullen (PL) made by teacher. I don't know if that counts though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40770/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-gebruiker).

Comment: The variant with the right-pointing tail looks like it might be derived from a cursive lowercase `r`. Perhaps you could look for an appropriate script font whose `r` glyph has enough of a loop at the beginning to look acceptable to you?

Comment: I didn't even know it is a Dutch-only symbol. I'm so used to it, it never occurred to me that it doesn't exist outside the Netherlands (and Belgium?) .

Comment: Not as beautiful as yours, but this was used on the approvel sticker of Veilig Verkeer Nederland http://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y184/adinsx/R17%20project/260720081031.jpg

Comment: Since nobody's said this explicitly, I will: this symbol will not be understood at all outside the Netherlands and perhaps other closely related countries. So, if you have an international audience in mind, it's probably best not to use it.

Comment: @Xenan I've never seen this symbol being used in Belgium. We use    checkmarks and crossmarks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Thought I'd have a go ...

Using [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/86), I took your "desirable" krul symbol and drew on it until I had something that looked fairly similar.  I used the `hobby` package to define the béziers rather than fiddling with control points (to avoid recomputing the path each time the symbol is used, I used a nifty feature of the `hobby` package that allows for reuse of a hobbily defined path; a bit of box magic puts the definition at the start of the document without - I hope - taking up any space).

The key feature of this implementation is the use of the `calligraphy` package to style the lines.  This, in my opinion, makes it look more like a letter drawn with a pen than a squiggle.

For added bonus, I made it scale according to the fontsize.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313281/86}
% Uses:
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54771/86} (hobby package)
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16899/86} (calligraphy)
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calligraphy,hobby}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\setbox0=\vbox{\tikz \path[use Hobby shortcut,save Hobby path={krul}] (-.2,0.25) ..  (0,.45) .. (.2,.65) ..  (0.3,0.76) .. (0.4,.97) .. (.1,.8) .. (.05,.65) .. (.3,.5) .. (.3,.4) .. (.15,.1) .. (.15,.05) .. (.3,.05) .. (1,.7);}%
}

\newcommand{\krul}{%
  \tikz[scale=1em/1cm] \calligraphy[copperplate,restore and use Hobby path={krul}{}];%
}
\begin{document}

This statement is true \krul

{\Large This statement is true \krul }

{\Huge This statement is true \krul }

\end{document}
```

[image: a tikzified krul]

Comment: I really like that you managed to make it look handwritten. If I read your answer correctly, this is the `calligraphy`'s doing, right? I'm not entirely familiar with all the commands you're using, so I'll need to let it sink in.

Comment: @gebruiker Yes, you're right: it is the `calligraphy` package (or rather, sub-package) that makes for the tapering effect.

Comment: The way you managed to simulate handwriting is awesome! Well done!

Comment: Of the current answers to this question, this is the only one that is actually immediately recognizable as a krul.

Comment: When I compile this code, I get a lot of errors.It starts with `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \g__prg_map_int`. The krul still appears correct.

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw I'm in the process of updating various of my libraries to match updates to the underlying LaTeX3 code.  That should be fixed in the latest version on [github](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3).  If you're feeling helpful, do try it against that version.  Otherwise, I'll get the updates on CTAN once I'm happy that I haven't inadvertently broken something else.

Answer (score 30):

If you are using pdfTeX then you can use `\pdfliteral` which draws the desired character directly. For example:

```
\def\krul{\leavevmode\hbox{\lower2.5pt\vbox to10pt{}\kern1.8pt
   \pdfliteral{q   
   1 j .7 0 0 .7 0 0 cm
   -2 1 m 
   3 2 4 5 4 7  c
   4 9 3 10 2 10 c
   1 10 0 9 0 7  c
   0 3 5 2 5 0 c
   5 -2 2 -3 1 -3 c
   S Q}\kern4.5pt}}

aha \krul.

\bye
```

yields

[image: Sample image of the krul sign]

Comment: Copy-pasting the code I can see that it draws a krul, but I am not really familiar with the `\pdfliteral`-command. Could you perhaps point me in a direction where the use of this command is explained?

Comment: @gebruiker `texdoc pdftex` I think.

Comment: @gebruiker `\pdfliteral` sends the direct PDF code to the PDF output. You need to know the basic PDF commands to understand it (or you can export image from inkscape as eps and do copy-paste). Your code using Tikz do the same in background, i.e. it generates `\pdfliteral`. There is a command `c` with six numbers preceding. This creates Beczier curve. For example the first Bezier curve from your example is `2.916 1.685 m  3.1 1.594 6.104 3.99 5.061 4.437 c`. I didn't use no geogebra, no inkscape, I only see the character picture and write the numbers. :)

Answer (score 29):

The `marvosym` package has a symbol called `\Denarius`.  The package documentation says, "The `\Denarius` symbol is also known as the correction sign “Deleatur”."   The deleatur (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dele) is a proofreading symbol that would seem to be the counterpart to "stet".

In fact, the topic of the correspondence of deleatur and krul was discussed at our sister website https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58320/what-is-the-name-or-unicode-for-this-symbol-similar-to-%E2%82%B0-dutch-called-krul, as some of the answers allude to.

Below I show it as given, and then two clipped versions, as some might not like the extra curl.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marvosym,trimclip,graphicx}
\def\krulA{\Denarius}
\def\krulB{\kern-1.5pt\rotatebox[origin=center]{22}{%
  \clipbox{5.5pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\rotatebox[origin=center]{-22}{\Denarius}}}\kern-2.5pt}
\def\krulC{\clipbox{4.5pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\rotatebox[origin=center]{-10}{\Denarius}}}
\begin{document}
\krulA, \krulB, or this \krulC.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The German wikipedia, https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deleatur, says that the symbol has a unicode of  U+20B0, though I have not yet found a font that contains it.  However, the German rendition is not quite the same as shown above.

Comment: I am very content with the simplicity of this answer. However I must say that some people will regard a krul without the upgoing tail at the end as unfinished or sloppy. But as implied by the picture in the SE-link you provided, this is not a hard definition in the eyes of everyone. I am editing the OP right now to point this out. Nevertheless, +1.

Comment: @gebruiker Thanks.  I don't have familiarity with the symbol to know the aesthetic markers that define it.  I did note a hint of an upturning at the end of the stroke, but it was not fully pronounced as in some renditions, to be sure.

Comment: According to the article linked in the Wikipedia article, the symbol is included as a German penny sign in several Microsoft fonts.
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfennig#Pfennigzeichen

Comment: @offbyoni The obsolete German penny sign is different, as it is derived from the *lower case* form of the Kurrent “d”, whereas the deleatur sign is derived from the upper case “D”. Furthermore, the rendering of the Pfennig sign U+20B0 (₰) is more usually as a “Pf” ligature; the obsolete variant is only used in a few fonts.

Comment: for reference, Open Sans has U+20B0 ₰, as does Lucinda Sans Unicode (the font used on TeX.SE, for me since I don't have Luncinda Grande)

Comment: U+20B0 is officially the German Penny Sign. It only happens to look like a loopy squiggle in some renderings. Such [homograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack)-repurposing hacks go against the Unicode philosophy. I would say that the Wikipedia page is wrong, or at least misleading. (For that matter, Denarius is the same hack.)

Answer (score 18):

I created the symbol using `tikz`.  I chose to scale the krul to about a letter size, but one can of course change this.

Here's the code:

```
     \newcommand{\krul}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.095]
\clip(2.8,0.95) rectangle (6.3,4.9);
\draw[very thick,color= black, ] 
(2.916,1.685) ..controls %0
(3.100,1.594) and %1
(6.104,3.990) .. %2
(5.061,4.437) ..controls %3 
(4.166,4.827) and %4
(3.077,3.853) .. %5
(3.535,3.119) ..controls %6
(3.857,2.580) and %7
(4.430,2.844) .. %8
(4.889,2.522) ..controls %9
(5.267,2.282) and %10
(4.086,0.929) .. %11
(5.129,1.238) ..controls %12
(6.150,1.548) .. %13
(6.150,1.548); %13
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

I got the code via Bézier curves in Geogebra. Once I got the krul, I exported the file as tikz-code.

In my humble opinion, it looks quite nice:

[image: Example of krul use]

Comment: (2.916755304486848,1.6858806827760646) ?  What is wrong in, say, (2.917,1.686)?

Comment: @Przemys Probably nothing, but as I said, I used the code that Geogebra exported. So everything was just copy-pasted. Removing the extra decimals thus would have been extra  work  for me. I hope you can forgive my lazyness :)

Comment: I've truncated to 3dp (if I could have rounded I'd have gone for 2dp, but truncation was much easier).  Find: `([0-9]\.[0-9]{3})[0-9]*([,\)])`; replace :`$1$2` in jEdit.  If you don't like it, roll it back, I won't be offended.

Comment: @ChrisH I don't mind. Nobody will be able to see the difference. I don't understand what you mean to say in the second sentence of your comment.

Comment: The second sentence was just a recipe for regex-based find/replace

Comment: Can´t you make a nice krul yourself and make it part of the collection of symbols? Are you Dutch, by the way, because I am too.

Comment: The last bézier is missing a control point.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html, a VERY useful site!

[image]

Comment: Did you find a Krul on Detexify? cos I didn't

Comment: The `\Denarius` symbol from the answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313301/36296 is in the list of symbols from Detexify and can be found.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some fonts which you could use with help of Lua- or XeLaTeX:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\symbol{"20B0}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\symbol{"20B0}  
\setmainfont{Consolas}
\symbol{"20B0}  
\setmainfont{Courier New}
\symbol{"20B0}
\setmainfont{Dejavu Sans}
\symbol{"20B0}  
\setmainfont{Symbola}
\symbol{"20B0}  
\setmainfont{Quivira}
\symbol{"20B0}  
\setmainfont{Code2000}
\symbol{"20B0}  
\setmainfont{Free Serif}
\symbol{"20B0}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go with an inverted ampersand, I made it lowered a bit, too:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand*\krul{\text{\scalebox{-1}[1]{\raisebox{-0.7\dp\strutbox}{\&}}}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Hello, world \krul}

Hello, world \krul

\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I would not consider this a krul. I realize that it is quite aesthetically defined, so people who aren't familiar with the symbol, might consider other symbols to be similar sooner then the people who are.

Comment: If you insist on downvoting my post, please let me know what's wrong with it. Thanks.