# Is there any way to change the design of a line?

Tags: rules, technical-drawing

I'm using `\line(){}` to generate a line for sort of decoration purposes, like having the title, such as Problem Set 1, and then separating it from the rest of the document by a line. I'm wondering if there's a way to change the design of the line (TikZ maybe?) instead of just line thickness.

Comment: You mention TikZ yourself. Why don't you see its manual for examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suitable package would be [`psvectorian`](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/vectorian/) which is based on `pstricks`. It contains a lot of borders, backgrounds, and separator lines. Take a look at it's documents.

There is a also lot of examples, here on TEX.SX. Take a look, for example, at

[Does anybody know a good source of (free) ornaments, decorations, frames, backgrounds etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41159/does-anybody-know-a-good-source-of-free-ornaments-decorations-frames-backgr)

[Looking for TikZ flourishes and vignettes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14594/looking-for-tikz-flourishes-and-vignettes)

Comment: Please add a link for `psvecorian`, as I couldn't find this package at CTAN.

Comment: It's not a package actually, if we define restrictly! but a collection of vectors in pstricks format. And it is still under development. I added the link, however it is not in english...

Comment: psvectorian is not on Ctan (the package has not been accepted but I don't know why). Now you have also pgfornament. It's not on Ctan but on my site. I'm waiting for the first official version and I will try to put on Ctan. perhaps without the vectorian symbols. I think that it's the problem.

Comment: @HassanZakeri Thanks for the links! One question lead me to another link for what I was looking for. Also, is there a English documentation for psvectorians since it's all in French?

Comment: @Halime I never came across an English manual, but I don't thinks you will need one. Although the shapes seem complicated, the syntax and usage is very clear and simple. There are just few options, which happen to have english (and standard) names, like for example width, height, ...