# Drawing Curved Arrow Using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the figure like the below one:

[image: Sample image]

The image is produced using the code below:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains,matrix,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=0pt,
 start chain = A going right,
arrow/.style = {draw=#1,-{Stealth[]}, 
                shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm}, % styles of arrows
arrow/.default = black,
    X/.style = {rectangle, draw,% styles of nodes in string (chain)
                minimum width=2ex, minimum height=3ex,
                outer sep=0pt, on chain},
    B/.style = {decorate,
                decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt,
                pre=moveto,pre length=1pt,post=moveto,post length=1pt,
                raise=1mm,
                            #1}, % for mirroring of brace, if necessary
                thick},
   B/.default = mirror, % by default braces are mirrored
                        ]
\foreach \i in {1,0,0,0,1,1,
                2,0,3,4,1,2}% <-- content of nodes
    \node[X] {\i};
\matrix (ML) [matrix of nodes,
              nodes=draw, dashed, row sep=1mm,
              row 1 column 1/.style={draw=red},
              left=11mm of A-1]
{   
    1\ 0\\
    0\ 0\\
    1\ 1\\
};
\draw   (ML.north -| ML-1-1.north west) -| 
        (ML.south west) --
        (ML.south -| ML-3-1.south west)
%        
        (ML.north -| ML-1-1.north east) -|
        (ML.south east) --
        (ML.south -| ML-3-1.south east)
        ;

\matrix (MR) [matrix of nodes,
              nodes=draw, dashed, row sep=1mm,
              row 1 column 1/.style={draw=red},
              right=11mm of A-12]
{   1\ 1\\
    1\ 1\\
    1\ 1\\
};
\draw   (MR.north -| MR-1-1.north west) -|
        (MR.south west) --
        (MR.south -| MR-3-1.south west)
%
        (MR.north -| MR-1-1.north east) -|
        (MR.south east) --
        (MR.south -| MR-3-1.south east)
        ;
\draw[B=,red]   (A-1.north west) -- coordinate[above=3mm] (a) (A-2.north east);
\draw[arrow, red] (ML-1-1.north) to [out=60, in=120] (a);
\draw[B]        (A-3.south west) -- coordinate[below=3mm] (b) (A-4.south east);
\draw[arrow] (ML-2-1.south) to [out=315, in=210] (b);
\draw[B]        (A-5.south west) -- coordinate[below=3mm] (c) (A-6.south east);
\draw[arrow] (ML-3-1.south) to [out=315, in=240] (c);


\draw[B=,red]   (A-7.north west) -- coordinate[above=3mm] (a) (A-8.north east);
\draw[arrow, red] (MR-1-1.north) to [out=120, in=60] (a);


\draw[B]        (A-9.south west) -- coordinate[below=3mm] (bb) (A-10.south east);
\draw[arrow] (MR-2-1.south) to [ out=240, in=315] (bb);
\draw[B]        (A-11.south west) -- coordinate[below=3mm] (cc) (A-12.south east);
\draw[arrow] (MR-3-1.south) to [out=210, in=315] (cc);


    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

However, I want to replace the **arrows** with something like the picture given below. These pictures were collected from Google images.

[image: Sample Desired Red Arrows]:

Any help or idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: So perhaps you should start by providing the code for the image you can already produce? Please post it in the form of a minimal document we can compile i.e. `\documentclass... <necessary preamble>...\begin{document}<picture code>\end{document}`. It is not clear to me what you want the result to look like really, since the images you've posted don't seem very similar to each other. What *exactly* do you want to change about the arrows you have? Don't forget to attribute the code appropriately if it is based on another author's work.

Comment: @cfr I think the OP wants to have the arrows increase thickness which is not going to be that easy.

Comment: Please make your code compilable. It needs a preamble! `\documentclass...`

Comment: @Alenanno Really? What's the relevance of the bottom image, then?

Comment: @cfr red arrows = replaced by increasing thickness,  black arrows = replaced by bottom image arrows.

Comment: @Alenanno Ah, OK. I read the earlier version of the question and didn't notice that sentence had been added in the edit. Thanks.

Comment: If the black arrows are made like those in the bottom picture, the upper pair will either have to move or they will obscure some of the information. How do you see that working exactly?

Comment: @cfr, I understand your point. I have updated the question already. Thank you so much.

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14283/stroke-with-variable-thickness. Note that MetaPost is far superior to TikZ for this purpose. Variable line thickness are simple in that kind of context - just a question of using the right pen. PGf/TikZ just isn't designed with this kind of use in mind. (Not sure about pstricks and friends.)

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14594/looking-for-tikz-flourishes-and-vignettes?lq=1.

Answer (score 7):

Since `start width` and `end width` were never specified, I created `\maxlinewidth=2pt` for the final line width and adjusted the algorithm.

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains,matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,bending}
% from Alain Matthes's solution at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14295/
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{%
  /pgf/decoration/.cd,
  start color/.store in =\startcolor,
  end color/.store in   =\endcolor,
  start width/.store in =\startwidth,% not used
  end width/.store in   =\endwidth,% not used
  start color=black!5,
  end color=black,
}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{width and color change}{initial}{
 \state{initial}[width=0pt, next state=line, persistent precomputation={%
   \pgfmathdivide{.5pt}{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}% not sure why .5pt works better than .75pt
   \let\increment=\pgfmathresult
   \def\x{0}%
 }]{}
 \state{line}[width=.5pt, persistent postcomputation={%
     \pgfmathadd@{\x}{\increment}%
     \let\x=\pgfmathresult
   }]{%
   \pgfsetlinewidth{\x\maxlinewidth}%
   \pgfsetarrows{-}%
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.75pt}{0pt}}%
   \pgfmathmultiply{100}{\x}%
   \let\y=\pgfmathresult
   \pgfsetstrokecolor{\endcolor!\y!\startcolor}%
   \pgfusepath{stroke}%
 }
 \state{final}{%
   \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgflinewidth}%
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
   \color{\endcolor!\x!\startcolor}%
   \pgfusepath{stroke}%
 }
}
\makeatother

\newlength{\maxlinewidth}
\maxlinewidth=2pt

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=0pt,
  start chain = A going right,
  arrow/.style = {draw=#1,-{Stealth[bend]}, line width=.4pt, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm}, % styles of arrows
  arrow/.default = black,
  X/.style = {rectangle, draw,% styles of nodes in string (chain)
    minimum width=2ex, minimum height=3ex, outer sep=0pt, on chain},
  B/.style = {decorate,
    decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt, pre=moveto,pre length=1pt,post=moveto,post length=1pt, raise=1mm, #1}, % for mirroring of brace, if necessary
    thick},
  B/.default = mirror, % by default braces are mirrored
  ]
  \foreach \i in {1,0,0,0,1,1, 2,0,3,4,1,2}% <-- content of nodes
  \node[X] {\i};
  \matrix (ML) [matrix of nodes, nodes=draw, dashed, row sep=1mm, row 1 column 1/.style={draw=red}, left=11mm of A-1]
  {
    1\ 0\\
    0\ 0\\
    1\ 1\\
  };
  \draw   (ML.north -| ML-1-1.north west) -| (ML.south west) -- (ML.south -| ML-3-1.south west)  (ML.north -| ML-1-1.north east) -| (ML.south east) -- (ML.south -| ML-3-1.south east) ;
  \matrix (MR) [matrix of nodes, nodes=draw, dashed, row sep=1mm, row 1 column 1/.style={draw=red}, right=11mm of A-12]
  {   1\ 1\\
    1\ 1\\
    1\ 1\\
  };
  \draw   (MR.north -| MR-1-1.north west) -| (MR.south west) -- (MR.south -| MR-3-1.south west) (MR.north -| MR-1-1.north east) -| (MR.south east) -- (MR.south -| MR-3-1.south east) ;
  \draw[B=,red]   (A-1.north west) -- coordinate[above=3mm] (a) (A-2.north east);
  \path (ML-1-1.north) to[out=60, in=120] node[pos=.9,name=ap] {} (a);% interestngly, coordinate won't work here
  \draw[decoration={width and color change, start color=yellow, end color=red}, decorate] (ML-1-1.north) to [out=60, in=114] (ap.center);
  \draw[-Triangle,red,line width=\maxlinewidth] (ap.center) to [out=114, in=120] (a);
%
  \draw[B]        (A-3.south west) -- coordinate[below=3mm] (b) (A-4.south east);
  \path (ML-2-1.south) to [out=315, in=210] node[pos=.9,name=bp] {} (b);
  \draw[decoration={width and color change, start color=lightgray, end color=black}, decorate] (ML-2-1.south) to [out=315, in=199.5] (bp.center);
  \draw[-Triangle,black,line width=\maxlinewidth] (bp.center) to [out=199.5, in=210] (b);
%
  \draw[B]        (A-5.south west) -- coordinate[below=3mm] (c) (A-6.south east);
  \path (ML-3-1.south) to [out=315, in=240] node[pos=.9,name=cp] {} (c);
  \draw[decoration={width and color change, start color=lightgray, end color=black}, decorate] (ML-3-1.south) to [out=315, in=232.5] (cp.center);
  \draw[-Triangle,black,line width=\maxlinewidth] (cp.center) to [out=232.5, in=240] (c);
%
  \draw[B=,red]   (A-7.north west) -- coordinate[above=3mm] (d) (A-8.north east);
  \path (MR-1-1.north) to [out=120, in=60] node[pos=.9,name=dp] {} (d);
  \draw[decoration={width and color change, start color=yellow, end color=red}, decorate] (MR-1-1.north) to [out=120, in=54] (dp.center);
  \draw[-Triangle,red,line width=\maxlinewidth] (dp.center) to [out=54, in=60] (d);
%
  \draw[B]        (A-9.south west) -- coordinate[below=3mm] (e) (A-10.south east);
  \path (MR-2-1.south) to [ out=240, in=315] node[pos=.9,name=ep] {} (e);
  \draw[decoration={width and color change, start color=gray, end color=black}, decorate] (MR-2-1.south) to [ out=240, in=322.5] (ep.center);
  \draw[-Triangle,black,line width=\maxlinewidth] (ep.center) to [out=322.5, in=315] (e);
%
  \draw[B]        (A-11.south west) -- coordinate[below=3mm] (f) (A-12.south east);
  \path (MR-3-1.south) to [out=210, in=315] node[pos=.9,name=fp] {} (f);
  \draw[decoration={width and color change, start color=gray, end color=black}, decorate] (MR-3-1.south) to [out=210, in=304.5] (fp.center);
  \draw[-Triangle,black,line width=\maxlinewidth] (fp.center) to [out=304.5, in=315] (f);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe somebody knows how to add arrows.... This is from [Alain Matthes's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14295/), applying it to the case in question.

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains,matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,bending}
% from Alain Matthes's solution at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14295/
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{%
  /pgf/decoration/.cd,
  start color/.store in =\startcolor,
  end color/.store in   =\endcolor,
  start width/.store in =\startwidth,
  end width/.store in   =\endwidth,
  start color=black!5,
  end color=black,
}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{width and color change}{initial}{
 \state{initial}[width=0pt, next state=line, persistent precomputation={%
   \pgfmathdivide{50}{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}%
   \let\increment=\pgfmathresult%
   \def\x{0}%
 }]{}
 \state{line}[width=.5pt, persistent postcomputation={%
     \pgfmathadd@{\x}{\increment}%
     \let\x=\pgfmathresult%
   }]{%
   \pgfsetlinewidth{\x/40*0.075pt+\pgflinewidth}%
   \pgfsetarrows{-}%
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.75pt}{0pt}}%
   \pgfsetstrokecolor{\endcolor!\x!\startcolor}%
   \pgfusepath{stroke}%
 }
 \state{final}{%
   \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgflinewidth}%
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
   \color{\endcolor!\x!\startcolor}%
   \pgfusepath{stroke}%
 }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=0pt,
  start chain = A going right,
  arrow/.style = {draw=#1,-{Stealth[bend]}, line width=.4pt, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm}, % styles of arrows
  arrow/.default = black,
  X/.style = {rectangle, draw,% styles of nodes in string (chain)
    minimum width=2ex, minimum height=3ex, outer sep=0pt, on chain},
  B/.style = {decorate,
    decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt, pre=moveto,pre length=1pt,post=moveto,post length=1pt, raise=1mm, #1}, % for mirroring of brace, if necessary
    thick},
  B/.default = mirror, % by default braces are mirrored
  ]
  \foreach \i in {1,0,0,0,1,1, 2,0,3,4,1,2}% <-- content of nodes
  \node[X] {\i};
  \matrix (ML) [matrix of nodes, nodes=draw, dashed, row sep=1mm, row 1 column 1/.style={draw=red}, left=11mm of A-1]
  {
    1\ 0\\
    0\ 0\\
    1\ 1\\
  };
  \draw   (ML.north -| ML-1-1.north west) -| (ML.south west) -- (ML.south -| ML-3-1.south west)  (ML.north -| ML-1-1.north east) -| (ML.south east) -- (ML.south -| ML-3-1.south east) ;
  \matrix (MR) [matrix of nodes, nodes=draw, dashed, row sep=1mm, row 1 column 1/.style={draw=red}, right=11mm of A-12]
  {   1\ 1\\
    1\ 1\\
    1\ 1\\
  };
  \draw   (MR.north -| MR-1-1.north west) -| (MR.south west) -- (MR.south -| MR-3-1.south west) (MR.north -| MR-1-1.north east) -| (MR.south east) -- (MR.south -| MR-3-1.south east) ;
  \draw[B=,red]   (A-1.north west) -- coordinate[above=3mm] (a) (A-2.north east);
  \draw[line width=.4pt, decoration={width and color change, start color=yellow, end color=red}, decorate] (ML-1-1.north) to [out=60, in=120] (a);
  \draw[B]        (A-3.south west) -- coordinate[below=3mm] (b) (A-4.south east);
  \draw[line width=.4pt, decoration={width and color change, start color=gray, end color=black}, decorate] (ML-2-1.south) to [out=315, in=210] (b);
  \draw[B]        (A-5.south west) -- coordinate[below=3mm] (c) (A-6.south east);
  \draw[line width=.4pt, decoration={width and color change, start color=gray, end color=black}, decorate] (ML-3-1.south) to [out=315, in=240] (c);
  \draw[B=,red]   (A-7.north west) -- coordinate[above=3mm] (a) (A-8.north east);
  \draw[line width=.4pt, decoration={width and color change, start color=yellow, end color=red}, decorate] (MR-1-1.north) to [out=120, in=60] (a);
  \draw[B]        (A-9.south west) -- coordinate[below=3mm] (bb) (A-10.south east);
  \draw[line width=.4pt, decoration={width and color change, start color=gray, end color=black}, decorate] (MR-2-1.south) to [ out=240, in=315] (bb);
  \draw[B]        (A-11.south west) -- coordinate[below=3mm] (cc) (A-12.south east);
  \draw[line width=.4pt, decoration={width and color change, start color=gray, end color=black}, decorate] (MR-3-1.south) to [out=210, in=315] (cc);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: lines without arrows]

Comment: You can add a REALLY short arrow to the fat end.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Actually, when I tried adding an arrow at all, My arrow heads ended up randomly sprayed over the picture in all directions.... So *I* can't, I suspect. At least, not right now ;).

Comment: Note that if you need many of these, you will want to externalise. This is *slooooooooooooowwwwwwwww*.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I wish that the down-voter would leave some constructive suggestions.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Twern't an accusation. It would be weird to comment and then return to vote it down 6 months later. Your answer seems an improvement over mine, so at least some good has come of the down vote :-).