# pgfplots arrow head behavior in 3D plots

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-arrows, 3d, arrow-curve

After getting tremendous help with getting my [3D plotting skills up to speed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338668/how-to-use-3d-polar-coordinate-system), I have another problem with drawing arrows and somesuch.

Consider the following code example:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{winered}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{
  colorbrewer,
}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.13,
}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{0.5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=3,
    smallarrowhead/.style={->,>={Latex[winered,angle=60:3pt]}},
    blob/.style={ball color=winered,shape=circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt},
  ]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\vev}{0.246}
  \begin{axis}[
      % for debugging purposes only
      % view={0}{90},
      hide axis,
      data cs=polar,
      samples=30,
      domain=0:360,
      y domain=0:.305,
      declare function={
        higgspotential(\r)={(\r^2-\vev^2)^2};
        % functions to calculate cartesian coordinates from polar coordinates
        pol2cartX(\angle,\radius) = \radius * cos(\angle);
        pol2cartY(\angle,\radius) = \radius * sin(\angle);
      },
      colormap = {whiteblack}{color(0cm)  = (white);color(1cm) = (black)}
    ]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{45}
    \addplot3 [surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort] {higgspotential(y)};
    \addplot3 [winered,thick,smallarrowhead] coordinates {
      (\angle,\vev,{higgspotential(\vev)}) ({\angle+15},\vev,{higgspotential(\vev)})
    };
    \addplot3 [winered,thick,y domain={0.9*\vev}:{1.15*\vev},smallarrowhead] (\angle,y,{higgspotential(y)});
    \draw [winered,thick,dashed] (0,0,{higgspotential(0)})
    coordinate [style=blob]
    -- ({pol2cartX(\angle,\vev)},{pol2cartY(\angle,\vev)},{higgspotential(0)}) 
    -- ({pol2cartX(\angle,\vev)},{pol2cartY(\angle,\vev)},{higgspotential(\vev)})
    coordinate [style=blob];
    \node[anchor=south] at ({pol2cartX(\angle,\vev)},{pol2cartY(\angle,\vev)},{higgspotential(0)})                   {\color{winered}$\left\vert\phi\right\vert=\frac{v}{\sqrt{2}}$};
    \node[anchor=south] at ({pol2cartX(\angle+15,\vev)},{pol2cartY(\angle+15,\vev)},{higgspotential(\vev)})          {\contour{white}{\color{winered}$\chi$}};
    \node[anchor=south] at ({pol2cartX(\angle,1.15*\vev)},{pol2cartY(\angle,1.15*\vev)},{higgspotential(1.15*\vev)}) {\contour{white}{\color{winered}$h$}};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: strange arrow head]

The end point of the red line along the curvature gradient (the one marked with *h*)looks strange - the arrow head points in a strange direction, and there seems to be something strange going on with the end of the line in general. How can I fix this to have the arrow head nicely point along the curvature?

**Bonus**: How can I make the arrow heads look *3D-like*, as if they were curved along the surface?

Comment: The built-in arrowheads are 2d.  You could overlay a 3d arrowhead on top (of a triangle cap).  See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295183/drawing-curved-arrow-using-tikz/332461?s=2|1.4419#332461

Comment: Not sure what to make if your link, it's a bit much to digest. Do you think this would help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267222/3d-arrows-with-tikz

Comment: Yup, cones would do it.  I was thinking ribbons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I present a workaround for your problem ...

I think TikZ/PGFPlots gets a bit confused by the near points and so messes to draw the arrow tip. To prevent this, I store two coordinates at the end of the curve and than draw (a line and) the arrow tip separately with the help of the previous stored coordinates.

Again: Have a look at the comments in the code for more details.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14 and TikZ v3.0.1a
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{winered}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        arrows.meta,
        spy,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
      compat=1.11,
    }
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
    \contourlength{0.5pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % just for the `spy' stuff
    spy using outlines={
        circle,
        magnification=2,
        size=5cm,
        connect spies,
    },
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    scale=3,
    smallarrowhead/.style={
        ->,>={Latex[angle=60:3pt]},
    },
    blob/.style={
        ball color=winered,
        shape=circle,
        minimum size=3pt,
        inner sep=0pt,
    },
]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\vev}{0.246}
    \begin{axis}[
        % for debugging purposes only
        % view={0}{90},
        hide axis,
        data cs=polar,
        samples=30,
        domain=0:360,
        y domain=0:.305,
        declare function={
            higgspotential(\r)={(\r^2-\vev^2)^2};
            % functions to calculate cartesian coordinates from polar coordinates
            pol2cartX(\angle,\radius) = \radius * cos(\angle);
            pol2cartY(\angle,\radius) = \radius * sin(\angle);
        },
        colormap={whiteblack}{
            color(0cm)=(white)
            color(1cm) = (black)
        },
    ]
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{45}
        \addplot3 [surf,shader=flat,draw=black,z buffer=sort] {higgspotential(y)};
        \addplot3 [winered,thick,smallarrowhead] coordinates {
          (\angle,\vev,{higgspotential(\vev)}) ({\angle+15},\vev,{higgspotential(\vev)})
        };

        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % remove `smallarrowhead` from the `\addplot' command to not plot
        % the arrow head (here)
        \addplot3 [
            winered,
            thick,
            y domain={0.9*\vev}:{1.15*\vev},
        ] (\angle,y,{higgspotential(y)})
            % add some coordinates at the end of the plot to later draw the
            % arrow head with these
            coordinate [pos=0.99] (A)
            coordinate [pos=1.0] (B);
        % draw the arrow head with the previously defined coordinates
        \draw [
            winered,
            thick,
            smallarrowhead,
            shorten >=-1pt,
        ] (A) -- (B);

%        % at spy point
%        % (that doesn't seem to work, although it should. Maybe the polar axis
%        %  confuses tikz here
%        %  --> "search" for spy positions outside the axis environment)
%        \coordinate (spy) at (axis cs:-0.2,-0.2,3e-3);
%        % (inside the axis this is correct, but also using `\spy' directly
%        %  inside the axis environment leads to the same wrong result)
%        \draw [green] (spy) circle (1cm);
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        \draw [winered,thick,dashed] (0,0,{higgspotential(0)})
                coordinate [style=blob]
            -- ({pol2cartX(\angle,\vev)},{pol2cartY(\angle,\vev)},{higgspotential(0)})
            -- ({pol2cartX(\angle,\vev)},{pol2cartY(\angle,\vev)},{higgspotential(\vev)})
                coordinate [style=blob];
        \node [anchor=south,winered] at
            ({pol2cartX(\angle,\vev)},{pol2cartY(\angle,\vev)},{higgspotential(0)})
                {$\left\vert\phi\right\vert=\frac{v}{\sqrt{2}}$};
        \node [anchor=south,winered] at
            ({pol2cartX(\angle+15,\vev)},{pol2cartY(\angle+15,\vev)},{higgspotential(\vev)})
                {\contour{white}{$\chi$}};
        \node [anchor=south,winered] at
            ({pol2cartX(\angle,1.15*\vev)},{pol2cartY(\angle,1.15*\vev)},{higgspotential(1.15*\vev)})
                {\contour{white}{$h$}};
    \end{axis}

    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % as mentioned above, here I searched for the spy coordinates
        \coordinate (spy) at (1.0,4.0);
        \coordinate (A)   at (5.5,2);
    % I don't have a clue why not (A) is shown exactly in (spy),
    % but because here just the magnification itself is of importance we don't
    % care about the rest ...
    \spy [blue,right] on (A) in node at (spy);
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: this solution is an overkill. I would love to see a general solution .

Comment: @CroCo, who does not love general solutions? But as it seems no one came up with another solution so far... If you have found one or came up with one, we will be very happy if you share it with us (here on TeX.SX).